# Using udev rules to create symlink to device which contains number of usb port its connected to

Tags: linux, udev

I need to create a symlink to usb device which contains number of ports it's connected to

This is my output of
udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyACM0 --attribute-walk

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.2/3-4.2:2.0/tty/ttyACM0':
KERNEL=="ttyACM0"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.2/3-4.2:2.0':
KERNELS=="3-4.2:2.0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="cdc_acm"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="02"
ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01"
ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="02"
ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
ATTRS{bmCapabilities}=="2"
ATTRS{iad_bFirstInterface}=="00"
ATTRS{iad_bFunctionClass}=="02"
ATTRS{iad_bFunctionProtocol}=="01"
ATTRS{iad_bFunctionSubClass}=="02"
ATTRS{iad_bInterfaceCount}=="02"
ATTRS{interface}=="CDC Abstract Control Model (ACM)"
ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.2':
KERNELS=="3-4.2"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="2"
ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="02"
ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="2mA"
ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 2"
ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0419"
ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="c0"
ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
ATTRS{configuration}=="CDC ACM config"
ATTRS{devnum}=="6"
ATTRS{devpath}=="4.2"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="a4a7"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0525"
ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.19.58 with 20980000.usb"
ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
ATTRS{product}=="Gadget Serial v2.4"
ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
ATTRS{speed}=="480"
ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
ATTRS{urbnum}=="118"
ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
```

In this case my device needs to be named "Device_3-4.2"
Probably I need to somehow extract KERNELS attribute of parent device but i don't know how.

Comment: did you find an answer for this at the end?